# difference between Attach and Single when retrieving an object to the memory

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I know I can use foreign key instead putting the whole object in the memory. Just for the curiosity, I wonder which approach is better: using Attach or Single() in this 1-to-Many relationship scenario? Which one is better in terms of performance?

Using Attach();

```
        Player myPlayer = new Player();
        myPlayer.FullName = txt_Name.Text;

        Team myTeam = new Team { TeamId = Convert.ToInt32(drp_Teams.SelectedValue) };
        db.Teams.Attach(myTeam);
        myPlayer.CurrentTeam = myTeam;

        db.Players.Add(myPlayer);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

And using Single():

```
        Player myPlayer = new Player();
        myPlayer.FullName = txt_Name.Text;

        int teamId = Convert.ToInt32(drp_Teams.SelectedValue);
        myPlayer.CurrentTeam = db.Teams.Single(t => t.TeamId == teamId);

        db.Players.Add(myPlayer);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Single` is always fetching data from database no matter is this data already loaded into context or not. First approach will not query database for the Team entity - thus it's better in your scenario.

Comment: then, can you tell me what `db.Teams.Attach(myTeam);` does? what does it put in the memory?

Comment: `Attach` just includes an entity into db-set in the `Unchanged` state without actually loading it from database. It is helpful when you know for sure that the entity already exists in the database. Attached entity won't be saved into database in `SaveChanges()`, until you change it in some other way later.